# Azure Logic Apps - SAP Connector also for SAP B1

Tags: azure-logic-apps, sapb1

Does the SAP Connector for AZURE Logic Apps also include a trigger connection to SAP B1? Couldn't find an answer yet in google.

Comment: Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't have a trigger to connect to SAP B1 from the SAP Connector but you can create a new customer or order in SAP B1 under Commercient (Preview) Connector.

[image]

You can refer more about [Commercient (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/commercientcpq/#default-connection) here.